# How does this function operate with partial application?

Tags: ocaml

```
let all_contain_true l =
  not (List.mem false (List.map (List.mem true) l))
```

How is partial application used to make this function work to see if all the lists in the giant list contain true

Answer (score 2):

The only partial application I see is `List.mem true`. When we evaluate this at the toplevel, we see:

```
# List.mem true;;
- : bool list -> bool = <fun>
```

This expression returns a function which maps a `list` of `bool` values to a `bool` based on whether the list contains the value `true`.

We can see this is action:

```
# let f = List.mem true;;
val f : bool list -> bool = <fun>
# f [false; true; false];;
- : bool = true
# f [false; false];;
- : bool = false
```

`List.map` takes a function and a list. `List.mem true` provides the function.

---

**Style points**

For what it's worth, the `|>` operator may be useful in streamlining this function, and we can give a name to that function.

```
let all_contain_true l =
  let contains_true = List.mem true in
  l |> List.map contains_true |> List.mem false |> not
```

You could also locally open the `List` module.

```
let all_contain_true l =
  List.(
    let contains_true = mem true in
    l |> map contains_true |> mem false |> not
  )
```

Comment: And now we have a lot more partial application too.